# access params hash in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I have a link

```
<%= link_to 'Add link', new_link_path(:link => {:item1_id => @item.id}) %>
```

passing to

```
def new
 @link = Link.new(params[:link])
 @items = Item.all
```

form is

```
<%= form_for(@link) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :item1_id %>
<%= f.collection_select :item2_id , Item.all , :id , :name %>
```

So I want to access like the image linked to the item1_id item. How do I access it?
i tried

```
@item1 = Item.find_by_id(params[:link])
```

and

```
@item1 = Item.find_by_id(params[:item_id])
```

but I don't know what is right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try:

```
@item1 = Item.find(params[:link][:item1_id])
```

Answer (score 3):

looks like you need:

```
  @item1 = Item.find_by_id(params[:link][:item1_id])
```