# Dashing - Is it possible to run same dashboard with optional URL parameters?

Tags: ruby, dashing

I want to run dashing dashboard with optional URL parameters, e.g.: "myGreatDashboard?filter=cars"

The idea is if I can reuse the same JOBS for the same dashboard with simply passing some url parameters which would change the data output.

I would need to access this parameter inside the jobs/*.rb script, is this possible? My guess is not, but just in case.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7440560/access-params-hash-in-controller

Comment: Please read "[ask]".

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get data into your dashboard.  You can either use a Job (which can send data to your dashboard on a schedule using the `send_event` method) or you can use the API.  The API is how your dashboard can be directly updated over HTTP, which is what you want here.  By sending a request with URL parameters to the API, you can have the dashboard update in a particular way.

To update a particular widget, you can send a request to `/widgets/widget_id`.  The body of the request needs to be proper JSON with at least your `auth_token`.  The `auth_token` can be found in the `config.ru` file.

For example:

```
 { "auth_token": "some-string", "extraUrlParam": "xxx" }
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea. Can you please add some complete code example?